# Decrypt difference integer values 1 and 2, using AesCrypto

Tags: java, encryption, aes

What causes the results below to be different?

```
--------------
IF Value = 1 :
--------------
String key1 = "123456";
String key2 = "654321";
String  x = AesCrypto.encrypt(key1, String.ValueOf(1));
String  y = AesCrypto.decrypt(key2, x);

Result --> y = ���8��VW&�S

--------------
IF Value = 2 :
--------------
String key1 = "123456";
String key2 = "654321";
String  x = AesCrypto.encrypt(key1, String.ValueOf(2));
String  y = AesCrypto.decrypt(key2, x);

Result --> y = null
```

why not produce a null value 1, is not equal to a value of 2? Although both failed to decrypt.

Comment: You can replace `String.valueOf(1)` with `"1"`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what library that is but when encrypting with one key, and decrypting with another I would expect undefined results.

Answer (score 0):

1. You must encrypt and decrypt with the same key when using AES encryption.
2. The key is to short, AES supports only 128, 192 and 256 bit keys.
3. The output of encryption is not a string, it is a series of 8-bit bytes.